# Using MacBook Pro Monitor for displaying Raspbian OS

Tags: raspbian, usb, pi-3

I have a Raspbian Pi 3 but I don't have a monitor nor mouse. How can I use macOS monitor to display the Raspbian on it? My Macbook Pro doesn't have an ethernet port. I wonder if there could be some sort of wireless hacks to this?

Basically I am trying to find a way not to buy USB keyboard, USB mouse and a compatible monitor.

[This hack](https://pihw.wordpress.com/guides/direct-network-connection/) doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are you sure that you need a direct connection? I'd assume that your macbook is connected to a [home router](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_router) of sorts (more often than not). So have to Pi connect to that router too and you're set to use `ssh` and `vnc` to remotely control the Pi.

Comment: that was something I didn't think of. Thank you.

Comment: There's of course one major drawback. W/o a display of its own (or the serial debug console) one is at mercy to the fact that all network demons start up. If the system freezes during boot (e.g. bad block on the SD card) or the network config is damaged (usually because the user tangled it) one can only guess what is happening.